# Where can I go to research the Glycemic index of specific foods

Tags: nutrition, nutrition-information

I hear people on this site throwing the term 'Glycemic Index' a lot and I'd like to familiarize myself with how the GI of specific foods affect my diet.

For instance, I have recently started eating potato bread instead of white bread and I'd like a way to compare the Glycemic Index of the two to see how the change will affect my current diet.

Is there a particular source that's good for looking up the GI of specific foods (like Wolfram Alpha is for researching nutritional facts)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always go to [glycemicindex.com](http://www.glycemicindex.com/).  They have a database of foods available.

NOTE: certain foods don't have any glycemic reaction like chicken, beef, etc.  However if you marinade them, you'll have to check out what the GI is on the marinade.

- South Beach also has a [GI food chart](http://www.southbeach-diet-plan.com/glycemicfoodchart.htm).
- A chart for [glycemic index and load](http://www.health.harvard.edu/newsweek/Glycemic_index_and_glycemic_load_for_100_foods.htm).
- And [gilisting.com](http://www.gilisting.com/).

Probably one of the most useful would be this:

[Self Nutrition Data](http://nutritiondata.self.com)

Comment: This is the first time I've seen nutritiondata.self.com referenced. What a great resource.